# Number of seconds Convert the Persian numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want number of seconds convert the Persian numbers (Countdown of 20 to 0), i try that, but i did not succeed, in following is my full code. How do i do?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JBzv7/

HTML:

```
<div id="#Seconds" style="font-size: 40px;">
20
</div>​
```

Jquery:

```
var rep = {
        '0': '&#1776;',
        '1': '&#1777;',
        '2': '&#1778;',
        '3': '&#1779;',
        '4': '&#1780;',
        '5': '&#1781;',
        '6': '&#1782;',
        '7': '&#1783;',
        '8': '&#1784;',
        '9': '&#1785;',
        ':': ':',
    }

var str = '';
var sec = 20

var timer = setInterval(function() {

    var sss = sec--;
    var arr = sss.split("");                        

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    str += rep[arr[i]];
    }
    alert(str)
    $('#Seconds').text(str);

   if (sss == -1) {
      alert('ok');
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
},1000);​
```

Comment: why are you splitting an integer?  `var arr = sss.split("");`

Comment: +1 for nicely providing link to jsFiddle with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function render(n) {
  var digits = [], r;
  do {
    r = n % 10;
    n = (n - r) / 10;
    digits.unshift(['&#', r + 1776, ';'].join(''));
  } while (n > 0);

  $('#Seconds').html(digits.join(''));
}

(function timer(current) {
  render(current);

  if (current > 0) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      timer(current - 1);
    }, 1000);
  }
}(20)); // the 20 is your countdown length
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EHAsW/

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML file, 
`<div id="#Seconds" style="font-size: 40px;">` is incorrect.  The id should just be `Seconds`, without the `#`.  The `#` prefix is your way of telling Jquery that `Seconds` is the id, as opposed to the class (which you prefix with `.`) or the type of tag (no prefix).  But it's not part of the id itself.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you have set the `rep` object is good for selecting the numbers, you can `split` the value of `sec` variable and read the related property of the object. Note that you should use `html` instead of the `text`.

Also change:

```
<div id="#Seconds" style="font-size: 40px;">
20
</div>​
```

to:

```
<div id="Seconds" style="font-size: 40px;">
&#1778;&#1776;
</div>​
```

```
var rep = {
        '0': '&#1776;',
        '1': '&#1777;',
        '2': '&#1778;',
        '3': '&#1779;',
        '4': '&#1780;',
        '5': '&#1781;',
        '6': '&#1782;',
        '7': '&#1783;',
        '8': '&#1784;',
        '9': '&#1785;',
        ':': ':',
    }

var str = '';
var sec = 20;

var timer = setInterval(function() {   
    var sss = sec--;
    if (sss == -1) {
      clear();
    }
    if (sss < 10) {sss = "0" + sss.toString()}
    var v = sss.toString().split("");
    str = rep[v[0]].toString() + rep[v[1]].toString();        
    $('#Seconds').html(str);     
},1000);

function clear() {
   clearInterval(timer)
   alert('okay')    
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JBzv7/7/)